# Trouble extracting a value from a slider input

Tags: javascript, html

I've successfully set up a slider input. The value correctly shows in the webpage, but I can't seem to extract the variable to use outside the slider function. Slider is one of many input types in a larger app.

I set the var declaration outside the function, so I thought output would be a global variable but it's not working. The variable is only showing correct output inside the slider function.

See code below:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">


  <p>Input Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>


<script>

var output_var=0

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

output.innerHTML = slider.value;
console.log("outside slider output", output.innerHTML)

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  output_var=output.innerHTML

  console.log("output_var inside the slider function - works correctly", output_var)
}

console.log("output_var outside the slider function - doesn't work", output_var)

</script>
```

I expect the output_var to show the final slider results regardless of whether it's inside the function or outside, but the correct value only shows inside the slider function. I've tried other ways and can't seem to get final slide value into a global variable. I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I'm fairly new to programming and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Tha console correctly shows

> output_var outside the slider function - doesn't work 0

it's 0 because that's what you initialized the variable **output_var** with.

```
var output_var=0
```

To get the actual value you need to initialize it like

```
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
output_var=output.innerHTML;
```

Otherwise it's true value won't be availabe before the oninput event has fired.

Here's the working code:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
var output_var = output.innerHTML;

console.log("outside slider output", output.innerHTML)

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  output_var = output.innerHTML

  console.log("output_var inside the slider function - works correctly", output_var)
}

console.log("output_var outside the slider function - doesn't work", output_var);

document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",function(){
console.log("output_var somewhere else", output_var);
});
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Input Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
<button id="theButton">What's the value</button>
```

Comment: Hi- Thanks. Tried that but didn't work. output_var outside the slider functions  equals 50 the initial value.

Comment: You can do it in one line: `output.innerHTML = output_var = slider.value;`.

Comment: @rodd I've included a sample to my answer above. Just hit 'Run code snippet' to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks. Tried your snippet. As you can see below, the outside the function value stays at initial value:                                                                   
output_var outside the slider function - doesn't work 50
output_var inside the slider function - works correctly 49
output_var inside the slider function - works correctly 51
output_var inside the slider function - works correctly 52

Comment: Sure - it's just executed once but shows the correct value of 50. So I'm not sure - what do you expect it to be?

Comment: The final slider value is what I'm trying to extract. So if the user slides to 55 I need to access that globally, not the initial 50.  Is there something I need to do ensure the output_var is set to the final slide value?

Comment: As soon as the oninput event fired the value of output_var  will be updated and you can access it from somewhere else with it's actual value.

Comment: I've included a button to my sample - whenever you click it you get the actual value of output_var.

Comment: Thanks. By "As soon as the oninput event fired" I assume you mean when the slider is moved and value is changed? If that's the case the output_var outside the function just seems frozen at initial value while the inside the function value moves up and down correctly.

Comment: How do you verify that it's frozen? Maybe there's a little misunderstanding how Javascript works. I think you assume whenever you move the slider and the oninput events callback function gets executed all code below this will execute again, right? Well, that's not the case. The line `console.log("output_var outside the slider function - doesn't work", output_var);` won't ever be reached again.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to by Obscure in his answer, you need to understand how the javascript is executing. You're defining the `slider.input` function and when that event fires(i.e when the slider value changes) you're setting the `output_var` value to the slider value. However your `console.log` outside the slider function is run the moment the page loads. It does not get updated after the `oninput` function is run, so `output_var` at that point is still the initial value.

If you had another button that fired an alert when clicked to tell you the `output_var` value, you would see that that does update correctly.

You need to imagine your code is all executed at once, but only the bit inside the `oninput` function is run every time the value changes - not all the code outside that. However, other **event listeners** will be able to access the updated value.
I suggest you look up how javascript code executes and try to gain more understanding of function scope to understand more.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
var output_var = output.innerHTML;

console.log("outside slider output", output.innerHTML)

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  output_var = output.innerHTML

  console.log("output_var inside the slider function - works correctly", output_var)
}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', () => {
alert("output var is now " + output_var);
});

console.log("output_var outside the slider function - doesn't work", output_var)
```

```html
 <button id="test">Click me before and after changing slider</button>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Input Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I see your point. I will explore a little bit more. I guess the value may indeed have changed, but because of how JS executes it's just not visible in the console log. I ran your snippet and it clearly shows the point you're making. But I suppose I don't need that click me button, but you added it to illustrate your point on the timing of event firing and how it shows up in console log (ie console log shows old value while actual value may be correct.

Comment: It's working now. Above code snippets and insights helped. Turns out I didn't need to add event handler, once I tweaked my code to reflect above comments.